# Split point - Ableton live

Tags: live-sound, ableton-live, live

I am a Grade I performer on the Keyboard and right now I am using Apple Mainstage as my performance tool. Lately I am feeling that i can get better performance on Ableton live, Since for my reaktor blocks, the CPU usage is shooting off.

I am thinking of using track activator buttons on tracks, with the help of Novation 61, which syncs with Ableton live nicely. My question is how to achieve split point in Ableton live and is there any performance improvement when it comes to Mainstage compared to Ableton live.

Answer (score 1):

Load an Instrument Rack and in that load Reaktor. In that click the Key option and set the range in which this instrument will trigger sound.

Open the side chain and load another Reaktor, for the left hand chords, click on the "Key" option and set the keyboard range you want this to trigger.